# Grow "by" age, or "with" age?

Tags: word-choice, prepositions

I'd like to ask the difference between "grow by age" and "grow with age". Which one is correct? If it's both correct, then what difference do they make?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe *grow by age* is the action of having one's age increase; as in the number of days/months/days is increasing.

Meanwhile *grow with age* is having some other characteristic (presumably size/maturity) increase as the age progresses.

Cheers